# Tasks showing up in the meetings schedule bar

Tags: sugarcrm

I am wandering if anybody can shed some light on this problem for me.

Are Sugar tasks ever meant to show up in the Scheduling bar at the bottom of the editeview when you are Scheduling a meeting or call?

There seems to be an intermittent bug in Sugar CE that sometimes shows tasks in the scheduling bar. This was highlighted to me when one of the users of the CRM kept complaining that the scheduling bar was always showing fully booked e.g. purple then when he scheduled a meeting it was showing double booked. I looked into this and found that he had created tasks that were a month long and that’s why the scheduling bar was showing fully booked. But his other shorter Tasks were not showing up in the scheduling bar at all. So to me it was unclear whether this is normal behavior or not.

I then tried it myself on a clean install of Sugar CE and the same thing was happening intermittently. I also noticed that when you delete the Task it does not remove it from the scheduling bar. I had to go into the database and remove the record and remove the cache folder before it would vanish.

Ever seen this behaviour?

I looked into the code and found where the scheduling bar is being created. It seems to be done entirely in JavaScript and the source file is `jssource/src_files/modules/Meetings/jsclass_scheduler.js`  and within that the `SugarWidgetScheduleRow.prototype.add_freebusy_nodes function` seems to be what is determining if its booked or not.  This JS function is getting its data from the `GLOBAL_REGISTRY['freebusy_adjusted']` but where is that populated about?

In order to debug this I need to know how the scheduling bar in Meetings and Calls is pulling in its data?

Surly this must be a bug?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok one of my colleges helped me solve this problem. There is a bug in modules/vCals/vCal.php line 129

```
get_activities($user_bean->id,
      array("show_calls" => true),
        $start_date_time,
        $end_date_time,
        'freebusy');
```

This param : array("show_calls" => true), should be to just false.

```
 get_activities($user_bean->id,
        false,
        $start_date_time,
        $end_date_time,
        'freebusy');
```

You may then have to go into the vcals database table and delete the db entry for an affected user, then when the user goes into meetings or calls and saves a meeting the db cache will be refreshed and the task will no longer show up on the scheduling bar.